# How to use ternary expression with arithmetic in interpolated string?

Tags: dart

I have a double variable named distance, which is in the unit KM, if it is less than 1 KM i want it to display it in meters and also multiply the distance by a 1000 to convert it into meters, so far this is what i came up with which works but is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
'${distance < 1 ? distance * 1000 : distance} ${distance < 1 ? 'm' : 'km'}'
```

i tried to shift the calculations into one ternary expression but it didnt work

```
'${distance < 1 ? distance * 1000 'm' : distance 'km'}'
```

Comment: I would recommend specifying what you mean by "cleaner". I assumed based on your last attempt that you just want one ternary expression like my answer succeed at, but it's really not clear. Saying "cleaner" is subjective(for example, I wouldn't use ternary expressions at all if I wanted cleaner code) and it may lead to the closure of this question for being opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to shorten it to a single ternary expression(in this case the conditional operator), you would have to use the `toString` method of `distance` and concatenate it to its unit with the following.

```dart
'${distance < 1 ? (distance * 1000).toString() + 'm' : (distance).toString() + 'km'}'
```

---

A likely better solution is to use

```dart
(distance < 1 ? "${distance * 1000}m" : "${distance}km")
```

which does not require `toString` as suggested by Irn.

Comment: Nitpick: The `?`/`:` operator is the *conditional operator*. There are more *ternary* operators in Dart than that one (a ternary operator is one taking three operands, like a binary operator takes two operands). For example, the `[]=` operator is also a ternary operator.

Comment: Another. probably more readable, option is:

`(distance < 1 ? "${distance * 1000}m" : "${distance}km")`

Comment: @lrn Would you mind if I stole that and added it to my answer?

Comment: Not at all. All use is fair if it gives better answers. :)